# Is there a less torturous way to INSERT INTO?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-4.5, sqlconnection

If I want to insert multiple objects into a SQL Server DB it seems I have to do this:

```
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Table1 (
            Param_1,
            Param_2,
            Param_3,
            ...
            )
            VALUES (
            @param1,
            @param2,
            @param3,
            ...
            )",conn))
            {
              command.Params.Add("@param1",...);
              command.Params.Add("@param2",...);
              command.Params.Add("@param3",...);
              ...
              foreach(var o in objects)
              {
                command.Params["@param1"].Value = o.Param1;
                command.Params["@param2"].Value = o.Param2;
                command.Params["@param3"].Value = o.Param3;
                ...
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
            }
```

Just putting this together has me pulling my hair out, and I have a table with 28 fields. I have to write out that long list 4 separate times, with only the most trivial differences (DB field names may use different naming convention). It seems crazy; is there a shorter way?

Entity Framework isn't an option for me here which would've been my first choice, I have to roll the code.

Comment: Could you use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)?

Comment: I'd never heard of it before; I'm not too keen on adding additional dependencies though.

Comment: I'm used to use xml to pass an object or a list objects that have many properties. You could serialize object in C# to string and deserialize it in sql

Comment: You only need to write out the list once (expression trees are most convenient here since no runtime reflection will be required: `o => o.Param1`). From there, all the rest can be handled through loops. (You don't need to write out the list at all if it can be obtained by enumerating all public properties of the object.)

Comment: Use ORM or at least have list of parameter names and create command, params progamatically.

Comment: @MarkC. how does that help? Then I have 28 parameters on the stored procedure too!

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't really follow, can you provide an answer? I'd also happily see an answer featuring Dapper in case it is worth using after all

Comment: If you want to insert a large number of rows use SqlBulkCopy combined with a DataTable or DbDataReader. You can convert collections to datatables easily using extension methods like MoreLINQ's `ToDataTable()`. SqlBulkCopy's performance is similar to BULK INSERT

Comment: You can also use [Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass multiple items as a single table-typed parameter to a stored procedure or script.

Answer (score 3):

If you are totally against using external libraries, how about this?

```
void Insert (Dictionary <string, SqlType> cols, Object [] objects)
{
    string colNames = string.Join (",", cols.Keys);
    string paramNames = string.Join (",", cols.Keys.Select (c=>"@"+c));

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Table1 (" + colNames + 
           ") VALUES (" + paramNames + ")",conn))
    {
          foreach (var col in cols)
          {
             command.Params.Add("@" + col.Key, col.Value);
          }

          foreach(var o in objects)
          {
            // Here you would have to list them all unless
            // your object o is a Dictionary<string, object> or a DataRow.
            command.Params["@param1"].Value = o.Param1;
            command.Params["@param2"].Value = o.Param2;
            command.Params["@param3"].Value = o.Param3;
            ...
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to create such a dictionary, why not create a DataTable and use SqlBulkCopy or a TVP? This will avoid looping, specifying the parameters and improve performance